# registration fields data is not clearing after registration in joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have a problem in joomla 2.5 registration page.
I am not using any joomla extension for registration. I am using joomla provided registration page.
When user registers with new details after successful submission an activation link is triggered to user mail  id. It is working fine. Now again if I go to home page or any other page in a site and come back to registration page previous entered details are still available in the fields. How to clear the previous data in the fields?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I've seen this happen once, but clearing the cache solved the issue, it never happened again.

Comment: Sounds like either a cache or browser issue. Try clearing your cache first. Are you suing any autocomplete extensions in your browser?